# Can determinant of a matrix be found without recursion?

Tags: c++, c, recursion, matrix

One can easily find the determinant of a matrix using recursion, but I was wondering if it is easy to calculate the determinant without using recursion, because recursion is very slow. Or is it too difficult to find the determinant without recursion?

Comment: Recursion isn't notably slower than iteration in a modern programming language.

Comment: Really? I don't believe so. You would use tons of stack for recursion. It would work for matrices upto certain sizes, but what about a 20x20 matrix?

Comment: Yes, the determinant can readily get calculated without recursion with great difficulty.

Comment: Who said you have to copy the matrix every time you recurse?

Comment: What is up with this downvoting. It is a legit question!

Comment: Your question seems to be soliciting a discussion, which isn't what StackOverflow is about.  Either that or it could be percieved as a veiled attempt at "plz to be sending teh codez."

Comment: No, its not soliciting discussion. I am just asking if someone knows a more efficient solution for finding matrix determinant than recursion.

Comment: I am not really a fan of the duplicate-question mechanism, but if you recast your question as "how do I compute a determinant efficiently" then it has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435133/what-is-the-best-matrix-determinant-algorithm and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886280/how-to-find-determinant-of-large-matrix  The good algorithms are based on deep mathematical insights, not just "hey, this naive recursion uses too much stack."

Answer (score 1):

Recursion can always be transformed into iteration and *vice versa*

Comment: Ya, but that transformation is usually very ugly. I want something neater.